# Function declaration in R and its evaluation?

Tags: r, function, magrittr

Sorry for not being more specific in my question title but I was not sure how to phrase it.

I am just trying to understand how function declarations work in R.

```
library(magrittr)
library(compiler)

fn1 <- function(x) {x + 1} %>% cmpfun()
fn2 <- (function(x) {x + 1}) %>% cmpfun()

fn1(1) # gives an error
fn2(1) # works as expected
```

Why do I need parentheses around the function declaration so that `fn2` works and `fn1` does not?

If `function` is just like any other function, then why are not `function` calls (as in function declarations) obeying the normal syntax... From the help page on `function`, its syntax is:

```
function( arglist ) expr
return(value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
fn1 <- function(x) {x + 1} %>% cmpfun()
```

is the same as

```
fn1 <- function(x) {
    {x + 1} %>% cmpfun()
}
```

So like the documentation says: `function( arglist ) expr` -- basically everything after the `function(x)` is being treated as a single expression. When there are parenthesis, it knows when to "stop" the expression.

Which is different from

```
fn2 <- (function(x) {x + 1}) %>% cmpfun()
```

which is more like

```
fn2 <- `%>%`( function(x) {x + 1}, cmpfun())
```

So the first is just defining a function while the second is actually calling the pipe operator.

Answer (score 2):

It’s a question of precedence: the first declaration is equivalent to

```
fn1 = function(x) ({x + 1} %>% cmpfun())
```

That is, `cmpfun` is called on the result of `{x + 1}`, not on the function declaration itself.

Unfortunately I can’t find a documentation of these precedence rules, and the lack of a formal syntax for R means that the only source for this is the R source code itself (or, in this simple case, its observable runtime behaviour).

Apart from this, you ask

> why are not function calls (as in function declarations) obeying the normal syntax

— This isn’t really relevant here (for the purpose of your question, it *does* obey normal syntax) but the reason is: because `function`, like some other things in R (`if`, `for`, …), is a special form that obeys a special syntax, defined by the language.

Comment: plus 1 for mentioning these other things in R that obey special syntax.